# What is the adjective that designates a thing or person that is still missed or mourned?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am struggling to recall a little-used adjective that would work similarly to a made-up word such as "bemourned," as in as in "our ----- old radio station that went defunct years ago."  Have tried many different search strings in Google, to no avail.  Thanks!

Comment: *lamented*, often used in the phrase “late lamented”

Answer (score 1):

You might be thinking of this **be-** word given by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/beloved)

> **beloved**
>   ADJECTIVE
>
> **1** Dearly loved.
>   *As in any beloved regional recipe, the ingredients vary from cook to cook.*

So the sentence could be

> [We miss] our **beloved** old radio station that went <strike>defunct</strike> *off air* years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [cherished](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cherished)?

> bringing the pleasure of love or caring about someone or something that is important to you

Another source, from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cherished):

> to entertain or harbor in the mind deeply and resolutely

Answer (score 0):

*Bemoaned* may be it.

*Bemoan* is to express distress or grief over; lament: to bemoan one's fate. 
A lost relative can be described as *bemoaned* since we miss them keenly.

As it sounds like your *bemourned* it may be what you were looking for.